# strange Flutter bug on turning on/off bluetooth permission using IOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth, crash

I am facing a strange bug as my title says.

I am using `flutter_blue_plus.dart` package on my project. When user request bluetooth permission, the program will redirect the page to Settings.

However, if I switch the bluetooth button `on/off` on system level settings, the program crashes and says `Lost Connection to device`. Anyone facing the same issue?

I checked several projects on github which have the similar functionalities, all of them get crashed. Even if I initialize the project, and then switches system level bluetooth without touch any bluetooth functionality.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add some of your code? Maybe this is a real bug in flutter blue plus. You could try to open an issue on their github page: https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus/issues

Comment: I feel like this is a flutter issue. To figure out what happens, I just created a very simple/basic flutter app from its template and included the flutter blue plus package but without putting any Bluetooth logic on this app, when I do the switch on my iPhone. The app crashed again with the same error. Now I am so confused. My device is iPhone Xs with iOS 17.4.1.